# Firefox Extension - including CSS in manifest.json

Tags: css, firefox-addon, manifest

My manifest is not working when I add `CSS` into it, while it works in Chrome Extension when I do like that.

Here how my manifest looks:

```
  "css": ["css/jquery-ui.css", "css/font-awesome.css", "css/simplegrid.css", "css/basic.css"],
  "js": ["jquery.js", "jquery-ui.js", "myPeaceFile.js"],
```

`myPeaceFile.js` works, `jquery`'s are working. But CSS files are not.

I previously asked question about jquery's not working. It looked like this:

`"js": ["peace.js", "jquery.js"]` - didn't work.

Then I was suggested this and it worked:

```
"js": ["jquery.js", "peace.js"]
```

Is it something similar? Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can attach CSS to pages using [Style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/stylesheet_style), in your `main.js` define a style and attach this style to the contentscript.

```
var { Style }   = require('sdk/stylesheet/style');
var style       = Style({
    uri: './bootstrap.css'
});

tabs.on('ready', function(tab) {
    let worker = tab.attach({
        contentScriptFile: [
            data.url("jquery.min.js"), 
            data.url("jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"),
            data.url("mycontent-script.js"),
        ]
    });
    attach(style, tab);
});
```

At the Style constructor in the second line you can pass a string, or an array of strings, that represents local URI to stylesheet. In this case the `./bootstrap.css` is in the `data` folder of the extension.